# Redirect user to subdirectory of windows file share

Tags: active-directory, share, network-drive

I have a large central network storage array that I make available on the network using Windows File Sharing. For obvious reasons, different shares only allow access to certain users/user groups, but there are a small number of shares that are automatically mounted when a user logs on to their AD connected computer; this is enforced using group policy.

One of these shares is called /users and it is setup with personal directories for each individual user on the domain like so:

```
\\storage.server\users\username1 --> C:\data\users\username1
\\storage.server\users\username2 --> C:\data\users\username2
etc
```

One of the share's I have enforced through group policy is setup like so, making use of the Windows environment variable '%USERNAME%':

```
\\storage.server\users\%USERNAME%\
```

This works exactly as I hoped it would.

However, when a user is manually attempting to access their personal folder (such as from a non-domain computer), they have to manually enter their user name or just go to `\\storage.server\users\` and then browse through the list of directories for their username.

What I would like to be able to do is setup a way for a user to be redirected/forwarded directly to their personal directory. So, for example, the user could enter:

```
\\storage.server\home\
```

And would end up seeing the contents of:

```
C:\data\users\%USERNAME%\
```

I do not need to worry about permissions or automatic directory creation. Both of those tasks are taken care of as part of the user creation task.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Typical way to do this is to [map a network drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/118452/how-to-map-network-drives-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/) to the user's home folder, e.g. with

```
NET USE u: \\storage.server\users\%USERNAME%\
```

...the user can access his files using just `U:\` and not have to type anything at all.

Comment: Yes, and I have this drive map provisioned using Group Policy. What I'm looking for right now is how explicitly to do it without having a pre-mapped drive. The use case is for a user wanting to access their personal folder from a non-domain computer and without having to type \\storage.server\users\%USERNAME%\